# What is the java.lang.String v4.e.d()?

Tags: android

```
String.format(Locale.US, "%.1f", fFoo)
```

The above code usually works fine. It threw the following exception at one time:

```
Class: java.lang.NullPointerException
 Stack trace: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String v4.e.d()' on a null object reference
```

Could anyone shed some light on how it is possible for String.format() to throw the exception?

Comment: Can you provide any information about `fFoo`? While [`String.format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.util.Locale-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) and even the underlying [`Formatter.format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) don't mention NPE, the Details section for Formatter says `Unless otherwise specified, passing a null argument to any method or constructor in this class will cause a NullPointerException to be thrown.`

Comment: Did that 'one time' happened on release build rather than debug? Because the `v4.e.d()` part of the error seems to imply that obfuscation might be happening.

Comment: @shriakhilc fFoo is just a float.

Comment: @IvanGarza the exception is from a released version. I used Retrace to deobfuscate the stack trace. I did not include the part of stack trace related to the app's code. The deobfuscation appears to work well at least for that part.